# Invariant form of adjective "genügend"

Tags: adjective

The dictionary [lists](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/gen%C3%BCgend) `genügend` as an invariable adjective, meaning that (as I understand) it cannot be inflected.

> Ich habe genügend Geld. (*not* genügendes Geld)

Is there a reason why this adjective is invariant? And are there other notable invariant adjectives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, *invariable* means that an adjective does not have comparative and superlative forms. That's certainly true for `genügend`. It does *not* mean that it's not inflected, as these examples show:

> Er hatte eine gerade noch genügende Leistung erbracht. Ein den Bauvorschriften genügender Dachstuhl ...

In your example, it's really used as an adverb, isn't it?

> Ich habe genügend Geld. Das Auto verfügt über genügend Leistungsreserven.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right. By the way, what does the sentence "Das Auto verfügt über genügend Leistungsreserven." mean?

Comment: The car has a sufficient power reserve = is sufficiently powerful for the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

The word has it's origin in the present participle of **genügen** and it's spelled the same way.

Thus ***genügend*** is also the present participle of ***genügen***. This is possibly the same with ***ausreichend***, ***hinreichend*** and other words. These are used adjectival and also adverbial.

> Dem Willen ihres Vater genügend, wurde sie Tänzerin. (*present participle*)
>   Ich habe genügend[e Mengen an] Geld dabei. (*adjectival*)
>   Die Ernte muss genügend schnell durchgeführt werden. (*adverbial*)

Answer (score -1):

You use "genügend" (here) to describe an amount of an *uncountable* thing.

> Ich habe genügend (viel) Geld/Milch/Schlaf/...

If the thing is countable, on the other hand, you can't use "genügend" alone. Even

> Ich habe genügend viele Äpfel.

sounds weird to me (may be regional); I'd say

> Ich habe hinreichend viele Äpfel.

Note that "genug" can be used in both cases.

> Ich habe genug Geld.
>   Ich habe genug Äpfel.

(The latter *may* be colloquial, though.)

Comment: Who says that? The "cannot use it alone with countables"-part? "genügend Äpfel" yields 2000 results on Google. "genügend viele Äpfel" only 3. "genügend viele Leute"... 2000. "genügend Leute" 300.000... I think that is a pretty clear indication that it CAN and sometimes even SHOULD be used with countable nouns. -1 https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22gen%C3%BCgend+Leute%22

Comment: @Emanuel: That only shows that people *use* it (cf ["wegen dem Wetter"](https://www.google.de/search?source=hp&q=%22wegen%20dem%20Wetter%22&meta=&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)). I don't think it's *correct* usage but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Raphael... if one usage is 100 times more common than the other, I think it is the correct one, no matter what Duden or grammar books say. Maybe it was wrong once but that ship has sailed.