# Warum wird `genügend` nicht dekliniert?

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

Ein Freund hat mir heute gesagt `Wir haben genügend Zeit`, und ich frage mich, warum ist es nicht `genügende Zeit`? Ich meine, Zeit ist ein weibliches Nomen, und in diesem Fall folgt einem bestimmten Artikel.

Danke!

Comment: https://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-gen%C3%BCgen.html

Comment: Ähnlich, auf Englisch: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12388/invariant-form-of-adjective-gen%c3%bcgend